# Slow performance in reliable collections with relatively large dataset

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a reliable service with 3 partitions. The data is partitioned reasonably equally between the 3 - it's almost exact. I have just under 3.95 million entries of the following contract across the 3 partitions

```
[DataContract]
public class Item
{
    [DataMember]
    public string StandardisedText { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Vendor{ get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Card{ get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Suburb { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public float Latitude { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public float Longitude { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Level1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Level2 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Level3 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Level4 { get; set; }
}
```

I have an upstream aggregate service which reports back a count across all partitions with the following code (*please ignore the terribleness of this code, its a quick and dirty POC to see how viable reliable collections are for reasonably large data sets*).

```
[HttpGet("")]
        public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogError("Getting all count");
                ServiceEventSource.Current.Message("Getting all count");

                var settings = new FabricTransportRemotingSettings { OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30) };

                var factory =
                                new ServiceProxyFactory(h =>
                                    new FabricTransportServiceRemotingClientFactory(settings));

                int total = 0;

                foreach (var servicePartitionKey in PartitionKeys)
                {
                    var proxy = factory.CreateServiceProxy<ITermTextService>(
                        new Uri("fabric:/Acme.Fabric.Refinery/Acme.Fabric.Refinery.RefineryStore"),
                        servicePartitionKey);
                    var count = proxy.Count().Result;

                    ServiceEventSource.Current.Message($"Searched partition {servicePartitionKey.Value} and found {count} values" );
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Searched partition {servicePartitionKey.Value} and found {count} values");
                    total += count;
                }

                return Ok(total);
            }
            catch (Exception excep)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Error in get all {excep.Message} {excep.StackTrace}");
                ServiceEventSource.Current.Message($"Error {excep.Message} {excep.StackTrace}");
            }

            return null;
        }
```

The count code is

```
public async Task<int> Count()
        {
            int i = 0;

            var termTexts = await TermTexts;

            using (var tx = StateManager.CreateTransaction())
            {
                var enumerable = await termTexts.CreateEnumerableAsync(tx);

                var enumerator = enumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator();

                while (await enumerator.MoveNextAsync(CancellationToken.None))
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }

            return i;
        }
```

The total time of this operation is 747165 ms (12 minutes). This is an integer on the wire - no large packets.

My question is, is this performance in the expected region or should I investigate this further? It could be that using a RC for this volume of data is a misuse, so we would need to look elsewhere. These response times imply also that there are disk reads involved, so another question is at what point would this occur and can this be configured? A read from hot storage I would imagine to be in the region below 50ms per partition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But is getting all data the typical use case for your application? If not, try focus on a real world scenario and measure *that* performance.

Comment: By the way, what are the specs of your node type(s)

Comment: Essentially we would need to get the data to filter in ways that couldn't be accounted for by a single partition, so we would need access to the full data-set. Such as a 'contains' query.

The node specs are reasonably high - SSD hybrid configs with over 64gb RAM per node. 

Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Ok. Did you find [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47009168/service-fabric-reliable-dictionary-performance-with-1-million-keys?rq=1)? Might give some valuable insights and tips

Comment: @KnowHoper have you tried to implement [state serializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.data.ireliablestatemanager.tryaddstateserializer?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceFabric_Data_IReliableStateManager_TryAddStateSerializer__1_Microsoft_ServiceFabric_Data_IStateSerializer___0__)? The data record is quite large so using effective serialization can reduce total size on disk and also improve read performance.

Comment: Yes, I tried Protobuf which increased the speed by a bout 1/4. I could have used a binary serializer, but 12 minutes is so far away from what we would consider acceptable - somewhere in the region of < 30 seconds, the ROI seemed limited

Answer (score 0):

If u enumerate millions of records asynchronously,  this performance is expected. If u use IReliableDictionary2, you can use the Count property directly. No need to enumerate all records. If u want to search by key, use CreateAsyncEnumerable function.

Comment: Thanks for this but the point of the POC was not to return a count specifically, it was more to iterate an entire collection. We are looking for a Spark style solution on ASF I think - a unicorn.

Comment: I agree with this @teeboy. Here are some more ideas:
1. If you have to search on N fields, use another dictionary with the N fields as the key and the value is the PK. This way, you search on these keys in memory, and then you go with all the IDs to the original dictionary and lookup by their keys.
2. If you really have to search on ANY field, you can still try out the option above (your limit in this case is the memory) or you can offload your data to a specialized external store where you can do stuff like this. Depends if you always need the last minute data or if you write a lot.

Comment: Also, you can call the Count() method on each partition in parallel.